# Adding WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET setting causes azure function app service to become unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

My customer has deployed an Azure Function app on my behalf so that I can deploy the bits of a blob trigger function app. The app service is integrated into a vnet with a subnet allocated to it. The storage account associated with the function has two private endpoints, one for blob and the other for file. The networking is also set to only allow specific virtual networks and subnets, which does include the subnet on which the function app is attached. The function app also has a private endpoint. In such a configuration I know there are certain configuration settings that are required, one of which is WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET = 1. However, every time I add this configuration setting the app service becomes unavailable via Kudu. If I don't have that setting the "c:\home" is not available and does not show in Kudu debug console.

I can't deploy the app (Visual Studio) without the setting as it fails due to not having access to c:\home\site\wwwroot, and with the setting the deploy fails due to the site not being available.

Comment: @bard please check which app service plan you are using? As mentioned in the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentovervnet). It is not supported in consumption plan

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya it's an EP1 plan.

Comment: Update: I left off WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET, but added to settings WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER = 168.63.129.16, and WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL = 1. I then took down the firewall in the storage account (Enabled from all networks). This allowed Kudu to access the c:\ drive and I was able to deploy the code. I then re-enabled the firewall on the storage account. App appears to be functioning now but can't reach the web api I have deployed on another subnet. Note: I tried adding back the WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET setting but that causes the blob trigger to be unable to communicate with the storage account.

Comment: @brad Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Also the WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER IP you provided, what IP is this?